# Ratio of ordered pairs with gcd larger than $\log\log\log N$

Tags: number-theory

We've been asked the following question. Show that

$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{|\{(a,b)\in {Z}^2 : 1\leq a \leq N, 1\leq b \leq N, gcd(a,b)>\log\log\log N\}|}{N^2}=0.$$

We have no clue how to approach this problem. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: I believe I have solved it:

Let $A$ be the set in the numerator. Notice that 
$$|A|\leq \sum_{d>\log\log\log N}\frac{N^2}{d^2}$$
This may be a strict equality, I am unsure. Then
$$\sum_{d>\log\log\log N}\frac{N^2}{d^2}\leq \frac{N^2}{\log\log\log N}+N^2\int_{\log\log\log N}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}dt= \frac{2N^2}{\log\log\log N}$$
Then, 
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{|A|}{N^2}\leq \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{2N^2}{(\log\log\log N)N^2}\rightarrow 0.$$

Does this look correct? It also agrees with the below comment that $\log\log\log N$ is a misnomer and just something small but still increasing with respect to $N$.

Comment: I think the $\log \log \log$ is a misnomer. It's just a small number in comparison to $N$. What if it was just a single $log$? or a fixed number like $3$? Can you make any progress then?